# How do I get Geolocation API to work in Dartium?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm trying to test in Dartium browser using the Geolocation API.  In particular I try doing the following

```dart
window.navigator
  .geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
    ..then((pos) {

      window.alert(pos.toString());
    })
    ..catchError((PositionError error) {
      window.alert("Error code: ${error.code}, Error message: ${error.message}");
    })
    ..whenComplete(() => window.alert("complete"))
    ;
```

Ignoring the fact I'm using window.alert here, All I get is an error with the following message "Error code: 2, Error message: Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400."

However the same code works in Google Chrome when I use "pub serve".  It also works with Firefox.  How do I overcome this error, and get it to work in Dartium?  Is it even possible?

### UPDATE

I took a look at the 403 bug and tried using the fix specified on this page http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys, and when I first tried this, I got my credentials and setting wrong, I was getting a 403 error, but once that was resolved, and all the APIs enabled, plus the environment settings of

```
GOOGLE_API_KEY
GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID
GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET
```

I was back to "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400.", so I conclude it isn't the same issue.  Though if someone can prove me wrong, I'd be happy.

### FURTHER UPDATE

This is a bug.  I've answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.

I posted this question on https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/UMJHJlQH7wc, where Seth Ladd asked me to open a bug.

I've opened a bug for this, https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15866.  So hopefully this will be resolved soon.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are running into this issue

[Geolocation giving 403 error](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179686#c18)

Should be fixable by providing Google API keys for Dartium

Comment: How would I do this in the DartEditor, would I do something like, assuming I'm using bash to launch DartEditor, export GOOGLE_API_KEY=aaaaaaaaaa\n GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID=1111111.apps.googleusercontent.com\n export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET=ccccc or would I have to compile the entire code base for Dartium myself and set the conf file with those settings as described in the link you provided???

Comment: Actually I tried following the instructions from this page http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys and while I was getting the credentials and setting wrong I was getting the 403 error, but as soon as I set things up as per instructions, I was back to the 400 error.  So I don't think it's the same issue

Comment: I'm upvoting you, as you allowed me to eliminate the 403 bug as the cause of my problems.  Thanks